# how to use dotconnect for oracle to call stored procedures with nested table as parameter

Tags: stored-procedures, parameters, dotconnect, nested-table

I want to pass a nested table ( OracleTable in dotconnection ? ) as a parameter to call the stored procedure in a package. The type *test002_table* is defined in the package. Codes of stored procedure are below:

```
create or replace package testPro is
    type test002_table is table of test002%rowtype;  
    procedure testInsert(tbs test002_table);
end testPro;

create or replace package body testPro is
    procedure testInsert(tbs test002_table) is
        i int;
    begin
        delete from test002;
        for i in 1..tbs.count loop
            insert into test002 values tbs(i);    
        end loop;
    end;
end;
```

A test written in PL\SQL runs sucessfully :

```
declare 
tab testpro.test002_table := testpro.test002_table();
item test002%rowtype;
i integer;
begin
  tab.extend();
  item.id:=1;
  item.name:='a';
  item.lev:=5;
  item.age:=55;
  item.address:='das';
  tab(tab.count) := item;
  testPro.testInsert(tab);
  commit;
end;
```

But I don't know how to call this procedure using dotConnect. I've tried the following way but without sucess:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = con; //OracleConnection con
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
OracleType tp = OracleType.GetObjectType("testPro.test002_table", con);
OracleTable table = new OracleTable(tp);
```

Dotconnect couldn't find the type. 
How could I get the required object of OracleType? Or could this problem be solved in other ways? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User-defined types declared in a package cannot be used outside of this package. Please define globally the type used with the OracleTable class:

```
create or replace type test002_type as object(
  -- list here the test002 columns
  c1 number,
  c2 number
);
/
create or replace type test002_table is table of test002_type;
/
```

JIC: ROWTYPE is a PL/SQL construct and not recognized in the SQL create type statement.